# CraftCMS 3 - Composer Update

Tags: craft3, yii

How can I update all the packages under `craft/app/vendor` for Craft CMS 3 (Yii 2)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The `composer.json` file (and the `composer.lock` file so you can't even reverse engineer `composer.json`) isn't shipped with the official release on purpose.

Craft 3 is still in development preview status (not even alpha release), but the next release will include updated Composer dependencies.